# Not getting SQL connection in IIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

I have developed my application in MVC4 and runs fine. but in server when i hosted, it fails. I moved my code to server there i added the edmx file and sql connection and am able to run it from VS. I published it from there and hosted it in IIS, am getting an Error as

"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'SEIU-ULTCW\ULTCAPP01$'."

Am using SQL server 2008 r2 with windows authentication
Connection string am using is

```
 <add name="CMSEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.CMS.csdl|res://*/Model.CMS.ssdl|res://*/Model.CMS.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=LTCSQL;initial catalog=CMS;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Its is the one auto generated when i added the EDMX file to application. 
two uses for the server 
1.Administrator domain ULTCAPP01
2.user1   domain SEIU-ULTCW.
user1 has administrative privileges.

Also Windows authentication is enabled in IIS.
Any help is appreciated..
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you take a read of this

[Integrated Security and SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

I draw your attention to this sentence near the top

> To connect to SQL Server using Windows integrated authentication, you must identify the Windows identity under which your ASP.NET application is running. You must also be sure that the identity has been granted access to the SQL Server database.

So basically if the account that your website is running under doesn't have any permissions against your SQL Server database then this would generate the error you are experiencing.

Judging by the error message the account is `SEIU-ULTCW\ULTCAPP01$` check the permissions given to this account in your SQL Server and application database.

Also just for clarity, when you run the project from within Visual Studio it will be using your windows account credentials which I guess have access to the SQL Server - hence why that works.

Comment: Can i specify the windows user account in the config file.

Comment: Make sure you have <identity impersonate="true"/> in your web.config this should allow IIS to impersonate the authenticated user that is accessing your application - their credentials should be passed to the SQL Server so as long as they have permission to access the database it should work.

Comment: hooray.. atlast ..

<system.web>
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<identity impersonate="true" userName="foo" password="bar"/>
</system.web>

am marking yours as answer.. Thanks a lot..